# Lookup tables localization

Tags: sql, sql-server

On an project where I use localization I have the following tables:

```
create table dbo.Posts
(
  Id int identity not null primary key clustered (Id),
  Created datetime not null,
);

create table dbo.PostsLocalized
(
  Id int identity not null primary key clustered (Id),
  PostId int not null,
  LanguageId int not null,
  PostTypeId int not null,
  [Text] nvarchar (max) not null,
  Title nvarchar (120) not null,
        constraint UQ_PostsLocalized_PostId_LanguageId unique (PostId, LanguageId)  
);

create table dbo.PostTypes
(
  Id int identity not null primary key clustered (Id),
  Name nvarchar (max) not null
);
```

So I am localizing the Posts with a PostsLocalized table but not the PostTypes table.

The PostTypes table is basically a lookup table as others I have in my database.

Do you think I should localize the lookup tables, for example, PostTypes?

I would add a new table named PostTypesLocalized with the localized names.

The same for other lookup tables like Genders, Countries, ...

Or should I localize the lookup tables only in the application?

**UPDATE**

To clarify:

1. All localized versions of one post has the same PostType.
2. I need to display the PostTypes in the UI that is why I need to translate them.

So I tried a new approach following the answer of @dasblinkenlight:

```
create table dbo.Posts
(
  Id int identity not null primary key clustered (Id), -- The id of the localized post
  Created datetime not null,
  PostId int not null, -- The id of the post
  PostTypeId int not null
  LanguageId int not null,
  [Text] nvarchar (max) not null,
  Title nvarchar (120) not null,
        constraint UQ_PostsLocalized_PostId_LanguageId unique (PostId, LanguageId)  
);

create table dbo.PostTypes
(
  Id int identity not null primary key clustered (Id), -- PostType localized id
  PostTypeId int not null, -- The id of the post type
  Name nvarchar (max) not null
);
```

**Considering (1) then Posts > PostTypeId should be related to PostTypes > PostTypeId.**

**But how can I do this?**

Comment: I would also recommend that you use the meaningful name for your primary key instead of ID. The simple ID is ambiguous and forces you to change the names of your columns based on what table they are in. This is real pain to work with as the system gets bigger. Give them a meaningful name and keep it consistent.

Comment: @SeanLange, sorry in which table?

Comment: All of them. For example you have a column in Posts named ID which becomes PostID in other tables. Just name it PostID in every table. Same with all your other keys.

Comment: I see, but see my code update ... That would become strange.

Comment: I disagree. Naming your primary key ID in every table is strange especially when the name of that column has to change in other tables. I was merely offering a suggestion about your naming conventions to help you in the long run. The fact that you have to include comments on your columns to explain where they come from is a clear example of why you should use 1 column name across all tables for the same piece of data. Feel free to ignore my comments. :)

Comment: I am not ignoring ... I am just trying to make a decision. And what would you call the PostId column I have now if I would change Id to PostId?

Comment: Yes exactly. It helps avoid confusion when the name is consistent across the entire system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on the usage of the `Name` field of the `PostTypes` table:

- If all uses of that field come from code and/or non-localizable scripts that you may have, localization is not necessary
- If the `Name` makes it to the end-user's view, you should localize the table.

If you need to localize `PostTypes`, a separate `PostTypesLocalized` table, in addition to the `PostTypes` table with locale-independent name, sounds like an appropriate solution.

You should consider the placement of the `PostTypeId` field, too. Would all localizations with the same `PostId` refer to the same `PostTypeId`, or would some of them be different? In case that all localizations of the same `Post` refer to the same `PostType`, the field should belong to the `Posts` table, instead of `PostLocalized`.

> should I localize the lookup tables only in the application?

Adding localization to your database counts as localization of your application. It is a good solution when you contemplate multiple applications using the same database structure.

Comment: I just updated my code ... I have one question left. How do you think I should do it?

Comment: @MDMoura Since all localizations of the same post will have the same `PostType`, your `Post` table should have `PostTypeId` field: `create table dbo.Posts(Id int identity not null primary key clustered (Id),  Created datetime not null, PostTypeId int not null)`. Language ID, Text, and Title should belong to `PostLocalized`, the way you had it in your original structure. You should create `PostTypeLocalized` with a language-specific name, referring to `PostType`.

Comment: So you saying it is not possible to have the same PostType associated to all translations and using only one Posts table as I added on my Update?

Comment: @MDMoura Of course it is possible. I think it's sub-optimal, though. Your updated `Posts` table looks like a modification of the original `PostLocalized` table, because it has a language ID, text, etc. Your original idea of keeping non-localizable fields in `Posts` and localizable fields in `PostsLocalized` provided a better separation between things representing the core of your data (i.e. `Posts`) and the data needed only for localization (i.e. `PostsLocalized`).

Comment: just for curiosity how would you set that relation using the second version of my tables?

Comment: @MDMoura I wouldn't use the second version of your tables as is, because it denormalizes your data needlessly. If you have to go with that version, add `LanguageId` to `PostTypes` to make sharing post types easier. Regardless of this, this new data model would introduce additional requirements on the `Posts.PostTypeId`, because it must refer to a proper localization for each post. This is highly suboptimal.